# Checking if a new row is added successfully in Realm

Tags: android, realm

I have one RealmObject class and my goal is to add new rows. Here is my RealmObject class

```
public class ZAccountTable extends RealmObject implements Serializable {
@Index
@PrimaryKey
private long id;
private String zAccountIdentificator="";
private Date openDate;
private Date closeDate;
private long amountInPeriod;
private long vatInPerion;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getzAccountIdentificator() {
    return zAccountIdentificator;
}

public void setzAccountIdentificator(String zAccountIdentificator) {
    this.zAccountIdentificator = zAccountIdentificator;
}

public Date getOpenDate() {
    return openDate;
}

public void setOpenDate(Date openDate) {
    this.openDate = openDate;
}

public Date getCloseDate() {
    return closeDate;
}

public void setCloseDate(Date closeDate) {
    this.closeDate = closeDate;
}

public long getAmountInPeriod() {
    return amountInPeriod;
}

public void setAmountInPeriod(long amountInPeriod) {
    this.amountInPeriod = amountInPeriod;
}

public long getVatInPerion() {
    return vatInPerion;
}

public void setVatInPerion(long vatInPerion) {
    this.vatInPerion = vatInPerion;
}

public long getOperationcounter() {
    return operationcounter;
}

public void setOperationcounter(long operationcounter) {
    this.operationcounter = operationcounter;
}

public long getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(long amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public long getVat() {
    return vat;
}

public void setVat(long vat) {
    this.vat = vat;
}

public long getOperationcounterAll() {
    return operationcounterAll;
}

public void setOperationcounterAll(long operationcounterAll) {
    this.operationcounterAll = operationcounterAll;
}

public boolean isSent() {
    return isSent;
}

public void setSent(boolean sent) {
    isSent = sent;
}

public String getSignature() {
    return signature;
}

public void setSignature(String signature) {
    this.signature = signature;
}

private long operationcounter;
private long amount;
private long vat;
private long operationcounterAll;
private boolean isSent;
private String signature="";


}
```

I can add a new row in my table tike this:

```
zAccountTable.setzAccountIdentificator("10");
    Date openDate;
    Date closeDate;
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");

    try {
        openDate = formatter.parse("2018-04-30 15:01");
        Log.e("Print result: ", String.valueOf(openDate));
        closeDate = formatter.parse("2018-04-30 16:01");

        zAccountTable.setOpenDate(openDate);
        zAccountTable.setCloseDate(closeDate);

        zAccountTable.setAmountInPeriod(10);
        zAccountTable.setVatInPerion(0);
        zAccountTable.setAmount(100);
        zAccountTable.setVat(0);
        zAccountTable.setOperationcounter(2);
        zAccountTable.setSent(true);
        zAccountTable.setSignature("signature");

        CoreApplication.realm.executeTransaction(realm -> {
            Number currentIdNum = realm.where(CashierTable.class).max("id");
            int nextId;
            if (currentIdNum == null) {
                nextId = 1;
            } else {
                nextId = currentIdNum.intValue() + 1;
            }
            zAccountTable.setId(nextId);
            realm.insertOrUpdate(zAccountTable);

        });

    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I have a problem ,Sometimes, something wrong in my code,I can't add new row,Is it a possible to check if new row added successfully and catch a error's result?

Comment: `I can't add new row` what does that mean?

Comment: I don't know.I have two buttons.in first onClick I try to save item and in a second button onClick I try to show row,and sometimes row's size is a same @EpicPandaForce

Comment: Hmm, `nextId` should always be new number, and therefore you shouldn't be accidentally overwriting previously saved objects... but that also means I'm not sure why you are experiencing what you are experiencing, as transactions always see latest version. So new ID cannot be outdated in a local Realm.